# Why does my Unity Shader mix whats infront of it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm not great with shaders but can get by. I'm using unity 2D mode

My shader works okay in normal circumstances. However..
Here's the set up:
There is a wall, in the wall is a door (using a camera to look into the room beyond).
In that room is a semi-transparent quad.
If I use unity default sprite shader no problem (but obviously I dont want to)
If I use my own shader it mixes in the wall infront of the object aswell.
I've tried using Unity's default shader for clues as to where I'm going wrong but to no avail.
appreciate all and any help..
A very basic version of shader code as follows..

A very basic version of shader code as follows:

```
Shader "Custom/Basic"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Outside", 2D) = "white" {}
        
        _OutTint("Outside image Tint",COLOR) = (1,1,1,1)
        _OutAmount("How much Tint",Range(0,1)) = 0

    }
        SubShader
        {   
    Tags { "QUEUE"="Transparent" "IGNOREPROJECTOR"="true" "RenderType"="Transparent" "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="true" "PreviewType"="Plane" }
    Pass {
    Tags { "QUEUE"="Transparent" "IGNOREPROJECTOR"="true" "RenderType"="Transparent" "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="true" "PreviewType"="Plane" }
                Cull Off
                Lighting Off
                ZWrite Off
                AlphaTest Off
                Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            
                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv1 : TEXCOORD0;
                    
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                    float2 uv1 : TEXCOORD0;

                };

                sampler2D _MainTex;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;

                float _OutAmount;
                float4 _OutTint;

                

                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.uv1 = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv1, _MainTex);

                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {

                v2f q = i;

                fixed4 col1;

                col1 = tex2D(_MainTex, q.uv1);
                col1 = lerp(col1, _OutTint, _OutAmount);
                return col1;
                }
                ENDCG
            }
        }
        FallBack "Unlit"
}
```